# Does the frShowHelp Work Anymore for Common Dialogs in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, dialog, common-dialog

I was trying to add a Help button onto my Open, Save, Find and Print common dialogs in Delphi 2009.

I thought the proper way to do it was to set frShowHelp to true in the Options property of the dialog:[image]

But when I do, the dialog comes up the same as without the option, e.g.:[image]

I'm expecting to see a Help button below the Cancel button, but it's not there.

I'm developing under Windows Vista. Did Microsoft eliminate the capability of adding the Help button to their common dialogs, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: TFindDialog is a VCL-provided dialog, not a Microsoft common dialog; so if anything is broken, it's probably not because of Microsoft.

Comment: That it not true. TFindDialog is a wrapper around Microsoft's Find dialog.

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646956.aspx

Comment: Correct @Remy, and this is the link to the Microsoft "Customizing Common Dialog Boxes" document that seems to indicate that the SHOWHELP value in the Flags should work. See "The Help Button" section at the bottom of the document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646951(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: There's something wrong here. I'm seeing the help button on my find dialogs when I set `frShowHelp`. I started with a vanilla project, added a TFindDialog, added `frShowHelp` option and invoked `FindDialog1.Execute(0)`. Help button present on D2010 and DXE2. Windows 7 x64.

Comment: For the two file dialogs, the new Vista dialogs don't have built in help options. You need to implement that yourself with [`IFileDialogCustomize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775912.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Find dialog**

Include `frShowHelp` in `Options` and the help button will appear. It's very hard to understand why that would not be working for you.

**Print dialog**

Include `poHelp` in `Options` and the help button will appear.

**File dialogs**

Now these did change when Vista was introduced. The new dialogs do not have, built-in, the capability to show a help button.

You can always revert to the legacy XP dialogs by setting `Dialogs.UseLatestCommonDialogs` to `False`. If you do that you can set `ofShowHelp`, `HelpContext` etc.

You should prefer to use the new dialogs if they available though. For those dialogs you need to use [`IFileDialogCustomize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775912.aspx) to add a help button.

In Delphi, for Vista and up, you would need to use `TFileOpenDialog` or `TFileSaveDialog` directly rather than `TOpenDialog` and `TSaveDialog`. You would create the dialog object and then request the `IFileDialogCustomize` interface from the `Dialog` property. The best place to do this is in the `DoExecute` event of the dialog control.

```
procedure TForm1.FileOpenDialog1Execute(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileDialogCustomize: IFileDialogCustomize;
begin
  FileDialogCustomize := FileOpenDialog1.Dialog as IFileDialogCustomize;
  FileDialogCustomize.AddPushButton(0, 'Help');
end;
```

Comment: I do confirm that the Help button does appear for me on the Print dialog when poHelp is added. It obviously uses a different mechanism, being poHelp instead of frShowHelp. I had tested my Find and Open dialogs for my question and assumed Save and Print would have been the same. But my Find Dialog is not showing the Help Button when I include frShowHelp. Something must be different in what I'm doing. So with that in mind, I'll research some more.

Comment: I was able to get the Help button to appear in another project. But it my application, it won't, even with a new FindFile dialog. Still researching ...

Comment: This is unbelievable. After I got the Help button on the Find dialog the other project. I went back to my project and tried again. To my amazement, the Help button now appears! I know it hadn't in my previous two dozen attempts. I have no idea why this fixed it. But that at least is working now.